# Is is possible to save a virtual desktop state?

Tags: windows-10

Is it possible to create multiple virtual desktops, open applications in each of them and then do some sort of saving so when I shutdown or reboot my computer these virtual desktops reopens those applications where they were in the screen?

Imagine I want 2 virtual desktops: one for a programming environment and other for trivial stuff like facebook, whatsapp, etc. That would be very nice if I could set a list of start up programs for each individual virtual desktop and set the initial position of each window (in case the applications couldn't open each at the last state, of course).

If this isn't a built in feature of windows 10, is there a 3rd party tool that implement this feature?